# Replace last digit occurrence in square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable like:

```
var text = 'researchOrganisationTrait.keywords[0].freeKeyword[1].texts[en_GB]';
```

Which I wish to maintain the index of the last occurrence (dynamic added content)

I have tried using the code like:

```
var text = 'researchOrganisationTrait.keywords[0].freeKeyword[1].texts[en_GB]';
text = text.replace(/\[\d*](?!.*\[)/, '[newIndex]');
alert(text);
```

But this does not replace `freeKeyword[1]` with `freeKeyword[newIndex]`

How to I match the last occurrence of square digit?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4eALF/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `\d`:

```
text = text.replace(/\[\d+](?!.*\[\d)/, '[newIndex]')
```

Comment: Probably want `\d+` to support multiple digit index

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I will use \d+ to support multiple digits as well. :-)

Comment: Thanks for comments. I update the regular expression to use `\d+`.

Comment: A question came to mind, what would it look like if it should match the first occurrence?

Comment: @meep, `text.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[newIndex]')` replace the first occurrence.